# Проверка переменных

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток. Существует несколько переменных,

**Например:**

`<?php
$param1 = "";
$param2 = "";
$param3 = "info";
$param4 = "";
$param5 = "";
?>`

**Вопрос:**

Каким образом можно проверить какая из этих переменных несет какую либо информацию и как потом определить какая именно это переменная (ее имя)?

**Примечание:**

В данном примере информацию несет переменная под названием `$param3`. ***Но*** в моем случаи я этого не знаю и мне нужно определить какая либо из этих переменных несет информацию и узнать ее имя.

`<?php
if(isset($param1)){
..
}
else{
..
}
?>`

Знаю можно таким образом проверить каждый носитель информации, а можно каким либо другим способом это узнать?

Comment: нужно получить именно имя? то есть строку с именем?

Comment: Нужно получить имя переменной.

Comment: имя переменной -- это строка?

Comment: Да. Именно ее.

Comment: Возможно ли это вообще? Или придется все isset`ом проверять?

Comment: >> Возможно ли это вообще? Или придется все isset`ом проверять?

а при чем тут вообще isset()?

Comment: Спасибо. А можно где то об этом методе почитать?

Comment: >Каким образом можно проверить какая из этих переменных несет какую либо информацию

В вопросе есть 99% ответа: посмотреть, не пустая ли переменная с именем "xxx". Как это сделать рассказывать не буду, потому что постановка задачи сама по себе идиотская до невозможности, а решать идиотские задачи - неверный подход, верный - поменять архитектуру :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот ответ, но вы архитектуру все-же смените, это просто как упражнение можно использовать и для дебага.

```
<?php
$param1 = "";
$param2 = "";
$param3 = "info";
$param4 = "";
$param5 = "";

$vars=get_defined_vars();
foreach ($vars as $key=>$value) {
if (substr($key,0,1)=="_" or $key=='argv' or $key=='argc') continue;
if (!empty($value)) echo "\$$key has $value\n"; //FIXME сделать обработку массивов и прочего
}
```

Comment: Вот что мне нужно было, спасибо)

Comment: такого точно не должно быть в рабочем скрипте

Answer (score 0):

ну как я понимаю, перемнные хранятся где то? или они просто разбросаны по скрипту? если в массиве, то просто пройтись по нему циклом. если не в массиве, то засунуть их в массив

```
$my_nonempty_vars = array();
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    if($value) {
        $my_nonempty_vars[] = $key;
    }
}
```

Comment: >> Спасибо. А можно где то об этом методе почитать?

не совсем понял? об isset()? http://php.net/manual/ru/function.isset.php
обо всём остальном там же. а вообще, если возникла такая задача, значит 99%, что-то делаешь не правильно. я думаю, тут лучше может быть вариант. для чего нужно имя переменной?